# Jquery datatable in play framework - $("#example").dataTable not a function

Tags: jquery, playframework, datatables

I'm trying to implement JQuery datatables in my play application.

Here is my code

```
    #{extends 'main.html' /}
    #{set title:'Customers List' /}
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/demo_table.css'}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/demo_page.css'}">
    #{set 'moreScripts'}
    <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
    <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
    <script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
        });
    </script>
    #{/set}
    <div class="others" align="center">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Header1</th>
                                <th>Header2</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Col1</td>
                                <td>Col2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
    </div>
```

When i run the page javascript throws an error

```
$("#example").dataTable is not a function
```

I checked all javascript/css files. All files were included.
What could be the error.

Comment: Did your app passes all requirement at http://datatables.net/usage/ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must load DataTables *AFTER* jQuery in your scripts section, and you must only include jQuery once.

Try removing the second (non-minified) request for jQuery and see how you go.

Comment: Thank you so much, I removed the non-minified jquery then the datatable was rendered but the css were not applied

Comment: Good to hear you've got it going. DataTables is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two reason for the error

1. You have not include jquery plugin before datatable plugin
2. You have include more than one time jquery plugin

   if you still have the problem than try to use jquery  plugin from cdn
   link is http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js
   and remove all other jquery plugins

Comment: Hey. I am using same thing for Play framework but it is popping an error :
DataTables warning: table id=data-table Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1. I am not sure what this is ?!!