# TypeError: jQuery(...).dataTable is not a function in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, datatables

I'm trying to install jquery datatable on grails 2.1 with no luck until now. I installed JQuery, JQuery-ui and jquery-datatable plugins. added the following code to main.gsp:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" />

        <r:require module="application"/>
        <jqui:resources />
```

and this code to my view:

```
  <jqDT:resources />
  <g:javascript>
     $(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('#demo').dataTable({
           sScrollY: '70%',
           bProcessing: true,
           bServerSide: true,
           sAjaxSource: '${request.contextPath + '/person/dataTablesData'}' ,
           sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
           aLengthMenu: [[100, 500, 1000, 5000, -1], [100, 500, 1000, 5000, "All"]],
           iDisplayLength: 500
        });
     });
  </g:javascript>
```

but when I tried to render it I got the following exception:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).dataTable is not a function
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: unrelated : isn't `sAjaxSource` should be something like  sAjaxSource: '${request.contextPath}'+'/person/dataTablesData'

Comment: Check if the javascript of the datatable is linked correctly, and after the jquery.

Comment: The datatables javascript probably isnt included after jQuery.

Comment: Still having the same error

Comment: I had the same problem, See this thread, it was resolved here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344047/jquery-datatable-in-play-framework-example-datatable-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but could be that you are using jQuery 2, which removes/replaces some functionality from previous versions. Try jQuery 1.10.1 and see if there is any improvement.